# Prevent Angular controller from loading using UI Router resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-ui-router, angular-promise

Im trying to use a promise to prevent a state from loading in UI Router `$resolve`.

```
$stateProvider.state('base.restricted', {

    url:'/restricted',
    templateUrl: 'views/restricted.html',
    controller: 'restrictedCtrl',

    resolve: { // user must be logged-in to proceed

        // authentication service checks session on back-end
        authenticate: function ($q, $state, $timeout, AuthService){

            AuthService.validate(token).then(function(res){ 

                if( res.data.response.status===1 ) { // authenticated!

                    return $q.resolve(); // load state

                } else { // authentication failed :(

                    $timeout(function() { $state.go('base.notfound') }); // load not found page
                    return $q.reject(); // do not load state
                }

            });
        } 
    }

})
```

This scheme works in terms of redirecting the user based on authentication results, but it looks like, upon failed authentication, the controller is still being loaded for a brief instant before the user is re-directed to the "not found" state.

I believe the reason is because Im running `AuthService` within resolve, but in an asynchronous manner. So the controller is loaded while `AuthService` does its thing but is then redirected once the callback function executes.

But isnt `resolve` inherently supposed to be blocking? That is, the controller doesnt load until `resolve` is "resolved"?

AuthService is basically this, fyi:

```
.service('AuthService', function($http){

    this.validate = function(token){

        return $http.get('http://my.api/validate/'+token);
    }
});
```

How can I modify this code to prevent loading until `AuthService`'s callback function has completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return a promise immediately, instead of doing so after the response from the service comes back:

```
return AuthService.validate(token).then(function(res){ ... }
```

Otherwise the router sees no return value instead of a promise, so it thinks it's OK to load the state. Then later when your AJAX request returns you end up redirecting, which is why you see a flicker.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the explanation I had the same problem